# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web, publish, parsing-error

i want to publish my site on server but i am getting this type of error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'egenc.SiteMaster'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="egenc.SiteMaster" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


Source File: /egenc/Site.Master    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Don't know whats going wrong with it ? How can i solve this error.

Comment: did you publish the bin?

Comment: How do you publish the website?

Comment: @Daniel: yes, i have publish bin folder too.

Comment: @walther: by right clicking the project solution and then publish website. is that okay?

Comment: And then? There are multiple settings you should set prior actual publishing, like the location where to publish, what to publish etc..

Comment: i have publish that on my local machine and then uploaded whole file to the server.

Comment: @walther: have you any idea what does error means ?

Comment: Well, it obviously can't find your c# class specified in `Inherits`...

Comment: so, how can i do it possible ? Have you a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a typo and it should look like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="egenc.master.Site" %>
```

That is if you didn't mess with the directive or class name...